# Laravel - transform field name with uppercase capital in json response

Tags: laravel

I'm working with Laravel 6.x, I have an "Item" class like :

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('subtype');
    });
```

In a controller, I have a route for get all items and return a json response like :

```
public function getItems()
{
    return response()->json([
        'datas' => Item::all()
    ]);
}
```

This function return this json :

```
{
  "datas": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "FIRE",
      "type": "9",
      "subtype": "5"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "FIRE",
      "type": "9",
      "subtype": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to dynamically add an uppercase on the first letter of each field before returning the json response, without change the laravel field name and the migration. I need to keep the field in lowercase in Laravel.

What I need is :

```
{
  "datas": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "FIRE",
      "Type": "9",
      "Subtype": "5"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "FIRE",
      "Type": "9",
      "Subtype": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do that simply ? I have a lots of class with a lots of fields in real. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) like this:

```
php artisan make:resource Item
```

then you will get a class in the *Resources* folder. That's where you edit the keys

**Resources/Item.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Item extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'Id' => $this->id,
            'Name' => $this->name,
            'Type' => $this->type,
            'Subtype' => $this->subtype,
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller, import the newly created resource and use it.

**Controllers/ItemController.php**

```
use App\Http\Resources\Client as ClientResource;

public function getItems()
{
    return response()->json([
        'datas' => ItemResource::collection(Item::all());
    ]);
}
```

There you go!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an additional getter in the model for the `name` attribute (with a new name). So you can have both name and the new attribute that you define.  Use `ucfirst` along with `strtolower`.

```
  public function getUCFirstNameAttribute($value)
 {
    return ucfirst(strtolower($value));
 }
```

OR

You can define an Items Resource. Inside the `toArray` method, you can use `ucfirst` on the `name` field.

```
   return [
        ...
        'name' => ucfirst($this->name),
        ...
    ];
```

Both ways you can keep the original field as is.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Generic solution :

```
public function toArray() {
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $name => $value){
        $newArray[str_replace('_', '', ucwords($name, '_'))] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Put this in a Model class, and after that just do : `Item::all()->toArray()`

This function transorm `my_awesome_field` to `MyAwesomeField`